# Refreshing collections filtered in the mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a collection which is filtered at the mapping level to enable soft deletion using an "isDeleted" column in the database.

The mapping looks like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.UploadedFiles).Where("IsDeleted = 0")
```

When I set the isDeleted property for some items the collection does not automatically refresh to reflect the deletion until I reload the entity.

Is there any way to force a "refiltering" without reloading the entity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Where clause in the mapping is to filter during fetching. It is not used at run-time, which is why you're not seeing UploadedFiles drop out of your collection when you set IsDeleted = true. I don't believe it is possible to refresh the collection without reloading the entity that owns it.

I would recommend expressing your intent in your object model.

```
private IList<File> uploadedFiles = new List<File();
public virtual IEnumerable<File> UploadedFiles {
    get {
        return uploadedFiles.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
    }
}
```

And then modifying your mapping to access your backing field...

```
HasMany(x => x.UploadedFiles)
    .Access.CamelCaseField()
    .Where("IsDeleted = 0")
```

Comment: The 'UploadedFiles' property in the object model is NHibernate's virtual get-set.
Do you mean to add another property (eg. NonDeletedUploadedFiles that filters upon the virtual property?

Comment: I assumed that UploadedFiles is a collection of objects. I'm suggesting having an explicit backing field and telling NHibernate to map to the backing field (as shown above). Your UploadedFiles property would then use LINQ-to-Objects to filter out deleted ones.